# create different modes of interaction in cocos2d

Tags: drag-and-drop, cocos2d-iphone, drawing

[EDIT:  Here's a link to a mockup of what I'm trying to create]

http://i53.tinypic.com/w9v2np.jpg

I'm trying to create an app for drawing diagrams in cocos2d that have different types of objects, but can't figure what is the best way to allow the user to choose which icon type to add to the diagram.  Basically, how do you create drawing modes in cocos2d?  should they be different CCScenes? Different CClayers?

The user should have the ability to select different icons for putting an object on the diagram, then drag from each to connect them with ccdrawline.  For example, give the user the ability to choose a circle icon and then anywhere they touch a circle is added as many times as they touch, then select a square and anywhere they touch have a square added to the diagram where ever they touch as many times as they touch.

This is my first foray with cocos2d and UI dev, but am fairly comfortable with C and Obj C for backend programming.

I already have the ability to add circles where ever a touch is detected, but unsure of the best approach to take for building the different modes of drawing objects.

What is the best method of creating drawing modes?  Assuming I need to create an elaborate toggle menu that allow the user to choose the object type to draw?

BTW, I choose cocos2d b/c of the amount of animations that need to be done to the diagram once its created.

Comment: Please make some images how you want your interface to look like and post them here

Comment: Tried to add a image but the site wouldn't let me due to being a new user.

Comment: Here's a link to a mockup at http://i53.tinypic.com/w9v2np.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create the DrawingLayer (CCLayer subclass), PaletteLayer and ControlsLayer. Create the Manager class (subclass from CCLayer if you want to make this class responsible for touches) which will provide the interface for interactions between those layers and store your diagram. The manager will also do such thins, as storing the current primitive is used to draw the diagram.

Comment: So it sounds like the best way to manage the mode model is to use numerous layers on a single CCScene.  How about the toggle menu for choosing the type of object to add to the diagram, should it be a CCmenu toggle or should I build something new?

Comment: @user: I suggest you to use another CCLayer with a CCmenu on it. Because it will be much simpler to add something later to the menu layer without changing your program structure